# Can't create projects (Modelsim)

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I've been doing VHDL on ModelSim since the beginning of the semester and for some reason, I can't create projects anymore now. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Modelsim but I still can't make it work. Could I have some help?

Comment: Any licensing issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows then try this:

1) Execute regedit

2) Find and rename the following key

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Model Technology Incorporated\ModelSim

rename to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Model Technology Incorporated\XModelSim

3) Restart Modelsim

The registry entry is not deleted when you un-install Modelsim. The key is recreated when you start Modelsim.

I would also suggest to delete the modelsim.ini file and libraries in your project.

Good luck,

Hans.